# Legend of barplot in R

Tags: r

I have a data in table like this
[I need a barplot for the same in R.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gJN4.jpg). So what I want is in the x-axis the High_score, Medium_score and Low_score should be plotted with the mean,max and standard deviation(means besides=TRUE )with three different color and the mean, max  and SD should be represented in the legend. Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please review [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions, and then provide a [minimal reproducible example/attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), including sample data. A [screenshot of your data/code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557) is not useful.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data_frame(
  "stat" = c("mean", "max", "sd"),
  "High_score" = c(55.6, 60, 5.1),
  "Medium_score" = c(40, 45, 4.3),
  "Low_score" = c(20, 28, 3.8)
)

df <- gather(df, key = score, value = value, -stat)

ggplot(df, aes(x = score, y = value, fill = stat)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image]